# Capture and replace first N occurrence of a pattern in a multiline string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following string from which i expect to replace the first two occurrences of `<br>` with a `\n` character.

```
<br><br><br>. Do not replace <br> here.
1. One
2. Two
3. Three<br><br><br>End of List. Replace first two <br> with \n
New line follows.
<br><br><br>. Do not replace <br> here.
```

I did write my regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/ZkeXCF/5). I am very new to regex and i am sure this is not an optimized solution.
After some tries i was able to select the `<br><br>` as a capturing group.
I want this 3rd capturing group to be my selected match so i can easly replace it with `\n`.
Can someone help me with this?

My expected output is:

```
<br><br><br>. Do not replace <br> here.
1. One
2. Two
3. Three\n<br>End of List. Replace first two <br> with \n
New line follows.
<br><br><br>. Do not replace <br> here.
```

```js
var str = `1. One
2. Two
3. Three<br><br><br>End of List
New line follows
`

console.log(
  str.match(/[\n\r].*(\d\.\s+)(?!.*[\n\r](\d\.\s+)).*((<br\s*\/?>){2})/)
);
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. What is the expected output exactly?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do beyond: `str.replace('<br><br>', '\n')`

Comment: Thank you guys for your response. I have edited my question to show you my expected output.

Comment: @Mark_M I am trying to detect if the **<br><br>** is at the end of a list.
If i find this pattern i expect it to be replace by a new line character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```js
let str = `<br><br><br>. Do not replace <br> here.
1. One
2. Two
3. Three<br><br><br>End of List. Replace first two <br> with \n
New line follows.
<br><br><br>. Do not replace <br> here.`;
console.log(str.replace(/(?<=[0-9]+\..*?)(<br>){2}/g, "\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```js
const initialString = `1. One
2. Two
3. Three<br><br><br>End of List
New line follows
`;
console.log(initialString.replace(/<br>?<br>/g, "\n\n"));

// or do you mean:
console.log(initialString.replace(/<br>?(<br>){1,}/g, "\n\n"));
```

Comment: @Kooilnc. Your solution is close but it selects all the <br> above and beneath the list. Can you please take a look at the update regex link i posted? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this regex can help you:

```
/(?:(([0-9])+.([\w]| ))*)<br><br>/g
```

It states that string to match must start with a number followed by . and some text and then your pattern < br > < br >. With ?: you create a non capturing group so you replace only < br >< br >.

Hope this helps.

```js
var str = `1. One
2. Two
3. Three<br><br><br>End of List
New line follows
`;

console.log(str.replace(/(?:(([0-9])+.([\w]| ))*)<br><br>/g, '\n'));
```

Comment: The solution selects the occurrences of digits as well. I want only the first 2 <br> tags to be matched and replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

str.replace(/<\br><\br>/g, '\n');